# Show that $N(H):=\{g\in G; gHg^{-1}=H\}$ is subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ subgroup of $G$, $N(H):=\{g\in G; gHg^{-1}=H\}$

I need to prove that $N(H)$ is subgroup of $G$.

It's almost the same question like :[How to show $\forall g \in G, gHg^{-1} = H \Leftrightarrow \forall g \in G, gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500049/forall-g-in-g-ghg-1-h-leftrightarrow-forall-g-in-g-ghg-1-subset)

But I need the inverse direction of the answer.

**Attempt:**
The inverse of $gHg^{-1}$ is:

$$\begin{align}(gHg^{-1})^{-1}&=(g^{-1})^{-1}Hg^{-1}=gHg^{-1}=H \\&\implies (gHg^{-1})^{-1}=gHg^{-1} \\&\implies \text{the inverse of element is the element}\end{align}$$

Is it true?

Comment: The inverse of a set!? Be careful, what you need to prove is that the inverse of each **element** that lives in $N(H)$ lives in $N(H)$ too,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $N(H)$ aren't $gHg^{-1}$ but $g \in G$ such that $H$ has that property.

If $g, g' \in N(H)$ then $$gg' H (gg')^{-1} = g(g' H g'^{-1})g^{-1} = gHg^{-1} = H$$ then $g\dot \,g' \in N(H)$

If $g \in N(H)$ then $g^{-1} H (g^{-1})^{-1} = g^{-1} H g = H$, because $gHg^{-1} = H$, then $g^{-1} \in N(H)$.

And you're done.

Answer (score 0):

You will need that $H$ is subgroup of $G$. Note that if $e\in G$ is the identity, then $e\in N(H)$ because $eHe = H$. Next, you want to show that if $g\in N(H)$ then $g^{-1} \in N(H)$. Equivalently, for all $h\in H$, $(ghg^{-1})^{-1}\in H$. But $(ghg^{-1})^{-1} = gh^{-1}g^{-1}$ is indeed in $H$ because $h^{-1} \in H$ and $g\in N(G)$.